# Set Default "From" address for email sent through Chatter Feed

Tags: email, lightning-experience, case, chatter, chatter-feed

I've created an Organization-Wide Address (Corporate CC) and I want this email to be the default "from" address when an operator send an email through the case Chatter Feed

[image]

as you see from the image, I can see "Corporate CC" in the "From" droplist, but the default is the email of the current User (User User). I tried, like someone suggested, to add the same address to the Feed View "Specify From Address(es)" configuration but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can pre-defined the from address on an email action. Open your action, click new on pre-defined field values section.
[image]

Select **from** in the field to be pre-defined and then select the email address you want to default for your email action in specific value dropdown and save it.
[image]

Read more here:- [Set Predefined Field Values for Quick Action Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values.htm&type=5)

Comment: It worked! Thanks man

Comment: its not working, for me. can you please help me out to understand more